# Blackberry Text Filter

Tags: text, blackberry, filter

I want a BasicEditField that lets me enter alphabets only...and a combination of upper case and lower case ...as in Jan, Feb...when i use the upper case and lower case filter that are there in BaiscEditField it allows either the entire string to be in upper case or lower case , not a combination.How do i achieve this?

Comment: are you shooting for the "tumbleweed" badge here? http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard's right, extend [TextFilter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextField.html), **UPDATE** according to [Marc's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016817/text-filter-localization/2017340#2017340):

```
 class AlphaTextFilter extends TextFilter {

    public char convert(char c, int status) {
        if (!validate(c))
            return 0;
        return c;
    }

    public boolean validate(char c) {
        return CharacterUtilities.isLetter(c);
    }
}
```

Then simply use

```
BasicEditField.setFilter(new SimpleTextFilter());
```

See also [BlackBerry Support Community Forums:Java Development:Input Text Validation](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Input-Text-Validation/m-p/111463;jsessionid=D0E59E8342D3A811C67C4F35A209FD4B)

Comment: will this filter work when the program is run on a device with some other language....i mean will the char's be mapped automatically..if not please let me know how to make this localized...