# Validation for textfield to allow upCase as first letter-Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, uitextfield, validation

How to allow first letter of an input in textfield to be caps.Or is it possible to change on textfield text change event.Also i want to avoid having a space as first character.(Though it may be used in middle of text)

Here is the code for textfield validation for testing for other parameters

```
    TextField1 = new TextField("\n Customer Name: ",null)
     {
            protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time) 
            {
            if (CharacterUtilities.isLetter(ch) || (ch == Characters.BACKSPACE || (ch == Characters.SPACE))) 
            {
            return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
            }
           return true;
            }
        };
     add(TextField1);
```

Please guide.Thanks

Reedit:

```
      AutoTextEditField auto = new AutoTextEditField("Name: ",EditField.NO_NEWLINE | Field.EDITABLE | AutoTextEditField.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE);

     add(auto);
```

Reedit 2:
Using below code prevent any spaces from being typed(at start or between).Also still there is no validation for Caps as first letter being done.
Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931475/blackberry-text-filter) for how I got the below idea

```
BasicEditField bf = new BasicEditField("BasicEditField: ","", 10,EditField.FILTER_UPPERCASE); 
     class AlphaTextFilter extends TextFilter
    {
      public char convert(char c, int status) 
      {
      if (!validate(c))
           return 0;
           return c;
      }

       public boolean validate(char c) 
       {
         return CharacterUtilities.isLetter(c);
       }
    }
    bf.setFilter(new AlphaTextFilter());
    add(bf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AutoTextEditField` instead of `TextField` with the following flags: `EditField.NO_NEWLINE | Field.EDITABLE | AutoTextEditField.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE`.

Don't afraid spaces in front of the real value. Just call `trim()` for final value.

Comment: Please check the reedit of what i have tried.It gives a compile error.And what is the usage of trim() method.Would be nice if you could cite an example based on mine.

Comment: @techie: Trim will give you the text by discarding the whitespace and newline before and after the text of an editfield.

Comment: @Nsr Thanks.Is that the right way i have implemented autotextedit(in the reedit) as it gave me some errors.